# d8 preprocess commerce product entity

Tags: 8, commerce

Where can i alter commerce product twig template variables?
When i display commerce product `mymodule_preprocess` and `mymodule_preprocess_entity` never called.

Doesn't exist `mymodule_preprocess_node(&variables)` for commerce product entity?

Thanks
Fabio

Answer (score 9):

You can use `hook_preprocess_commerce_product` like so:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_commerce_product(&$variables) {
  $product = $variables['elements']['#commerce_product'];
  ...
}
```